# How to update a single event without duplicating the rest of the events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, google-calendar-api

I am currently using app script to sync my google sheet to google calendar. The process is quite simple, my script only takes a date and title from the spreadsheet and creates an all day event on that date with that title.

The problem I am facing is that if I accidentally key in the wrong date or I have to update one of the dates inside the spreadsheet, on running the scheduleShifts function again, all the events are created again which results in many duplicate events that I did not intend to be there. I'm trying to find a solution that helps either updates the title of the event or deletes the event and create a new one in the case where the date that is in the spreadsheet is wrong.

It also isn't very efficient to update the data in the spreadsheet and then update the calendar because in the event where quite a few dates or titles have to be changed, it would take quite a bit of time to change them all in the calendar. It would also be very troublesome to delete the current calendar, create a new one, copy that id into the spreadsheet and then update everything again.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
function scheduleShifts() 
{
  /*Identify calendar*/
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  /*Import data from the spreadsheet*/
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("C4:F73").getValues();

  /*Create events*/
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++)
  {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var title = shift[0];
    var date = shift[3];

    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
  } 
}

/*Make the script shareable for others to use*/
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule shifts', 'scheduleShifts')
      .addToUi();
}
```

I have tried to avoid duplicating events by retrieving all the events with Advanced Calendar Service, pushing their titles into an array and then verifying with IndexOf. However, I am unsure if this method will work if the title stays the same while there is an update in the date of that event.

The code that I referenced from to do this:

```
var existingEvents=Calendar.Events.list(calendarId);
var eventArray=[]; 
existingEvents.items.forEach(function(e){eventArray.push(e.summary)});                                                    
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
  var shift = signups [x];
  var startTime = shift[0];
  var endTime = shift[1];
  var inspector = shift[2];
    if(eventArray.indexOf(inspector)==-1){ 
      eventCal.createEvent(inspector, startTime, endTime);
    }else{
      Logger.log('event exists already');
    }
  }
```

If anyone needs more info feel free to ask in the comments, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could (1) write the event ID to the spreadsheet for each created event, both to inform that the event has been created and to identify this event in case it should be updated, and (2) create an `onEdit` trigger that will use [Event: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) to update the event that was edited in the spreadsheet. Do you think that would be appropriate for your case? If the answer's yes, I'd consider posting an answer, while providing more details on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus, that sounds like a great idea. Sorry but I am a complete beginner at this, I only just started this yesterday. Do you mean using e.range to get the cell/cells that have been edited then creating a new event on the calendar from there?

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if this workflow is appropriate for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have developed a script to create events using data from a sheet.
- You want to be able to update previously created events while avoiding creating duplicates.

#### Step 1. Avoid creating duplicates:

In order to avoid creating duplicates, you could make the script write the corresponding `eventId` when each event has been created. This way, next time the script runs, it can check whether the `eventId` is populated (in which case the event already exists), and only create the event if it doesn't exist. It could be something like this (in this sample, the `eventIds` are written to column G):

```js
function scheduleShifts() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  const signups = spreadsheet.getRange("C4:G7").getValues();
  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    const shift = signups[x];
    const title = shift[0];
    const date = shift[3];
    const eventId = shift[4];
    if (eventId == "") { // Check the event doesn't exist
      const newEvent = eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
      const newEventId = newEvent.getId();
      spreadsheet.getRange(4 + x, 7).setValue(newEventId); // Write new eventId to col G  
    }
  }
}
```

#### Step 2. Update events:

Regarding the update process, I'd suggest you to [install an onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onedit), either [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). This this action requires authorization, a simple `onEdit` trigger would not work here (see [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).

This way, you can use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to only update the event corresponding to the row that was edited, thus avoiding having to update all events every time, which would make the process very inefficient. The update process itself would consist on calling [setTitle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#settitletitle) and [setAllDayDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setalldaydatedate).

The function fired by the `onEdit` trigger could be something like this:

```js
function updateEvent(e) {
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(editedRow, 3, 1, 5).getValues()[0];
  var eventId = editedData[4];
  try {
    var event = CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId);
    event.setTitle(editedData[0]);
    event.setAllDayDate(editedData[3]);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("There was a problem updating the event. This event might not exist yet.");
  }
}
```

#### Notes:

- You may not want to manually set the range (`C4:G73`) if the number of events might vary. You can use methods like [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) no make this range dynamic, based on the spreadsheet content.
- The `eventId` that are used here, corresponding to [Class CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event), are not identical to the API [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events). Take this into account in case you use the [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).

Comment: This is a great little solution.  I love it.  However, when I use the updateEvent function, wth an onEdit trigger, I get an oauth error.  when i run it as a manually triggered event, with named ranges rather than the (e) range, it works like a charm.  Some further investigation tell some that I can't use an onEdit trigger to edit something that requires authentication, even if I put authentication in the scope.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions

am I missing something?

Comment: never mind.  found a stupid workaround.  I have an onEdit function that stores the row of the edited data in a cell on the spreadsheet. Then my updateEvent function, which is *also* triggered on a change picks up the data based on the info in that cell.